# Почему не срабатывает сравнение строк в C#?

Tags: c#

Есть такое условие:

```
if (queryObj["DeviceID"].ToString().Trim() == @"USB\VID_0403&PID_6001\A900ER2T")
{
  // TODO
}
```

В `queryObj["DeviceID"]` лежит в точности такой же текст как и справа при сравнении. Даже вывел его в MessageBox для наглядности:

[image: MessageBox c DeviceID]

При это условие не срабатывает - в чем подвох?

Сравнил на длину строк:

```
1) USB\VID_0403&PID_6001\A900ER2T##30  // где 30 длина строки
2) string str2 = @"USB\VID_0403&PID_6001\A900ER2T"; // 30
```

Сейчас проверка такая:

```
string PID = "0403";
string VID = "6001";

MessageBox.Show(str_PID + " | " + str_VID);

if (str_PID == PID && str_VID == VID){
    Сюда не заходит при этом str_PID = 0403 str_VID = 6001
}
```

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Сравните для интереса длины строк для начала.

Comment: Хорошо, а так: `string s1 = queryObj["DeviceID"].ToString().Trim(); string s2 = @"USB\VID_0403&PID_6001\A900ER2T"; for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) if (s1[i] != s2[i]) MessageBox.Show("Position " + i);`?

Comment: Но вы же говорили, что длина обеих строк равна 30. Что-то тут не так.

Comment: И при чём тут faq?

Comment: Упростил код - обновил вопрос

Comment: Можете привести минимальный пример, чтобы воспроизвелось у нас?

Comment: А как объявлен queryObj? Может, у него ToString выводит не содержимое, а совсем даже имя класса?

Comment: возможно в строке невидимые символы. посмотрите на отдельные char так: queryObj["DeviceID"].ToString().Trim().ToCharArray()

Answer (score 2):

Попбробуйте с помощью метода `CompareTo`. Дело в том что `==` сравнивает две ссылки на объекты и определяет, ссылаются ли они на один и тот же экземпляр. Метод `CompareTo` предназанчен для проверки двух объектов на эквивалентость

```
string str = @"USB\VID_0403&PID_6001\A900ER2T";
if(str.CompareTo(@"USB\VID_0403&PID_6001\A900ER2T") == 0)
  {
   //TODO
  }
```

У меня он возвращает `TRUE`.

Comment: для `Object.String` `operator==` сравнивает значения, а не ссылки.